# Angular fails routing to lazy loaded modules after deploy

Tags: angular, typescript

I've recently published a new Angular app, which implements lazy loading.

Now, app compilation goes well, no error is show and running it in local environment for debug or using `ng serve` (or `ng serve --prod` to emulate the behaviour while in production mode) the app works fine and I can succesfully navigate from an eager loaded module to a lazy loaded one and vice versa, without errors.

---

### THE ISSUE:

If I run the app in the server (so using `ng build --prod` and then publishing it), I can't navigate from the first default eager loaded module (the homepage) to a lazy loaded module.

---

### ERROR STACK

The errors I get in the console are the following:

1. **error:**

   > ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.
   >   Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.

   **displayed when…** trying to navigate to any lazy loaded module, at the first time
2. **error:**

   > ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'LazyModule' in './lazy/lazy.module'
   >   Error: Cannot find 'LazyModule' in './lazy/lazy.module'

   **displayed when…** I try to navigate to a lazy loaded component again, after the first error showed up

**An interesting fact** is that when displaying these errors (expecially the second), it doesn't throw an error 404 not found, it's just a "normal" Angular error without any 404 status.

---

### MY CODE:

**project structure**

```
app.module.ts (& app.routing.ts)
|__lazy.module.ts (& lazymodule.routing.ts)
|__admin.module.ts (& admin.routing.ts)
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
// ... imports …
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'lazy',     
    loadChildren: "./lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule",
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',     
    loadChildren: "./admin/admin.module#AdminModule",
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: SelectiveStrategy, useHash:true });
```

**selective.strategy.ts**

```
// ... imports ...
@Injectable()
export class SelectiveStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {

    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
        if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
            return load();
        }
        return Observable.of(null);
    }
}
```

**lazymodule.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FooComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'foo',
    component: FooComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: NewElementComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

---

### VERSIONS:

**server** Windows Server 2012 R2

 **IIS** 8.5.9600.16384

 **angular/common** 6.1.5

 **angular** & **angular-cli** 6.1.4

---

### MY TRIES:

1) Tried to execute locally the `ng build --prod` generated files. It works.

 2) Tried to execute the app (locally) with `ng serve --prod`, but nothing seems to work

 3) Tried to add `useHash:true` option as you can see in the `RouterModule.forRoot` of `app.routing.ts` file above. Didn't work.

 4) Tried to move the routing inside the `app.module.ts` file. Didn't work.

 5) Tried to use a root relative path as `src/app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule`. Didn't work.

 6) Tried to copy in the server folder the files generated from `ng serve --prod`, but nothing.

 7) Tried to update all of my npm packages, but nothing.

---

What am I doing wrong? Is it a code issue or a server one?

*Let me knwo if you need more infos/code sections*

Answer (score 2):

I've found a temporary solution. Unfortunately it seems a permanent fix is something the angular team will have to take care of as it is an issue with the production build aot and build-optimizer.

For now, you have to disable aot and build-optimization. You can do this in one of two places either on the command line for a one time effect:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Or for a permanent effect in your `angular.json`, change your production configs to:

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

note the `false` for aot and build-optimizer

Answer (score 1):

use fat arror function for lazyLoading, so there no need to worry about module path

here's is an example

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'lazy',     
    loadChildren: () => LazyModule,
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',     
    loadChildren: () => AdminModule,
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working… This time I get the following error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded` while trying to navigate to a lazy loaded module. What could have I missed?

Comment: u can't use aot with this